# Unable to import in typescript file in nodejs

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am trying to import the underscore module in a Typescript file, but its creating trouble because when I run the typescript module in node, it throws an error:

```
Code:    
import _ = require('underscore');

Error:
import _ = require('underscore');
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
    at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to compile the TypeScript file. Then, run the generated .js file in node.

Comment: I have a file watcher in Webstorm (the IDE I'm using) that does that automatically. Are there any other possibility?

Comment: Either WebStorm is failing to correctly compile the file, or you're running node on the .ts instead of the .js